# Apply a substitution over every element of an array

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I have an array of file names. Names are of the format `company_ID_timestamp`.
How do I apply a substitution on the array without running a loop?

```
for ( my $i=0; $i < scalar @todayFiles; $i++ ) {
    $todayFiles[$i] = s/_20[0-9]{10}//;
}
```

Comment: BTW, don't you want to anchor your regex to the end of the string so that it doesn't accidentally clobber, for example, the ID? as in `s/_20[0-9]{10}$//`

Comment: @haukex. I cant. I neglected to mention in the question but the full format of the file is company_ID_timestamp.ext where ext is the file type extension

Comment: Then you could use [`File::Basename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) to split up the filename, or modify your regex, e.g. `s/_20[0-9]{10}(?=\.\w+$)//`

Answer (score 3):

Unless you want an ugly hack, you're going to want some kind of a loop, even if it's hidden with a [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html), or a `for` [statement modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers).

```
s/_20[0-9]{10}// for @todayFiles;
```

The following works in Perl v5.14 and up (because of the [`/r` modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s/_PATTERN_/_REPLACEMENT_/msixpodualngcer)). This one makes sense if you don't want to modify the original array:

```
my @otherArray = map { s/_20[0-9]{10}//r } @todayFiles;
```

And here's a shorter/better way to write that C-style loop you showed:

```
for my $filename (@todayFiles) {
    $filename =~ s/_20[0-9]{10}//;
}
```

The latter one works because the [`for` aka `foreach`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) loop actually aliases the variable `$filename` to the elements of the array being iterated over.

Comment: Thanks Haukex
I will probably use the last one

Comment: *"Unless you want an ugly hack"* how will any hack, ugly or otherwise, avoid the necessity of applying the same substitution to every element of an array?

Comment: @Borodin Something like this runs the regex over a single string: `@todayFiles = split "\0", join("\0", @todayFiles) =~ s/_20[0-9]{10}(?=\.\w+(\z|\0))//gr;` and I guess it's a matter of opinion whether this fits the OP's request *"without running a loop"* 

Comment: @haukex: There is a `/g` modifier on that substitution, so it still uses iteration. I'm pretty sure that the restriction is arbitrary. We can't tell exactly why the OP has chosen to eliminate iteration from the toolbox, but I'm guessing that they've seen `map` and want to use it, without realising that it's a tool of *expression* rather than implementation.

Answer (score 0):

To apply a substitution to every element of an array, there is no way but to iterate over those elements

That said, you can tidy up your code a lot by using `for` as a *statement modifier* and employing the `$_` default variable

```
s/_20[0-9]{10}// for @todayFiles;
```

This still iterates over the entire array, but the code is a lot tighter